# How to set a breakpoint in code to debug PHP

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

I'm debugging a PHP process using [xdebug CLI](https://xdebug.org/docs/dbgpClient).

I can attach to the process and set up breakpoints using `breakpoint_set`. However, they need to be set each time and cannot be defined on the code itself.

Is there any way to set a breakpoint in code? Something like `debugger` in JavaScript? That is, I do not want to set the breakpoints in the IDE by clicking on the left, this is what all guides suggest.

Comment: It will likely depend on your IDE, for example PHPStorm will allow you to set breakpoint just by clicking on the line that you want to debug.

Comment: @Xiidref, updated question. Clicking on the IDE is not what I want. I'm using the CLI for debugging so it is **not** connected to the IDE, I want something in the code

Comment: [xdebug_break](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions#xdebug_break)

Comment: thanks @shingo, that works. I can accept if you write it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have plans to make the `dbgpClient` that you mention, remember breakpoints that have been set through it. I haven't had the time to implement that yet.

For now, you can use the [`xdebug_break()`](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions#xdebug_break) function to interrupt the execution flow, and make the debugger pause.